# How to open password protected pdf using itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using iText library to read PDF files. It's working fine for all the pdf files, except for password protected ones. I used some way by using the overloading constructor of `PdfReader` class

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("locked pdf file","password".getBytes());
```

But it is showing show error like :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1OctetString

Is there any other to read password protected pdf file? or should I include bouncy castle into my project library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from iText 2.0.0 you need the BouncyCastle jars. You need to download it from [its site](http://www.bouncycastle.org/). More info can be found from here:

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-org-bouncycastle-asn1-ASN1OctetString-td2151526.html)

Comment: @RAVITEJA, what error you are getting? and update your question accordingly

Comment: I already mentioned the error in my code. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1OctetString

Comment: bouncycastle is a crypto library for java, it seems to be used in the process. Add the library to your classpath, you can find it here: http://www.bouncycastle.org/

Comment: @Unni V Mana Thank you very much Mana

Comment: Please let me to know which version of bouncycastle i have to use, because some classes are not present in latest versions

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
   PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(String.valueOf(file));
   pdfReader.isEncrypted();
} catch(IOException) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```